# Is anyone using a Nintendo Wiimote on Blender?

Tags: camera, external-applications

I'd like to use a Wiimote to control my camera. To make subtle handheld shots.
Except one video from 2014, I don't find any resources.
I guess there should be many other good reasons to use the Wiimote to create 3D.

Has anyone tips?

thanks

Comment: This question doesn't appear to have anything to do with using Blender so is likely to be closed.

Comment: I don't know much about Wiimote, but if I wanted to control the camera with a handheld thing I would go for Arduino(or maybe ESP32), accelerometer/gyroscope, serial communication via USB or Wifi and pyserial that could connect it to Blender via Blender's Python API. That seems to me quite difficult, but doable + it will likely be a lot cheaper than Wiimote. If you google "accelerometer Arduino control Blender" you can find some successful projects. Sounds like quite a big project though.

Comment: @JohnEason Yes it does

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys well, you can get a Wiimote for almost nothing on second hand. Arduino is beyond my competences. I saw some sample video about what you talked about, it seems very experimental and hard to control, unfortunately.
Around 2008-2010, a lot of people were using the Wiimote for all sorts of things on PC but all this community seems to be long gone...

Comment: Yeah, that's why I say I don't know much about Wiimote. It might be perfect for this - just don't know. I do know that it is possible with Arduino or other micro-controllers.  Arduino Nano clone is like 5 eur, accelerometer around 4 eur. So that's real cheap - just additional benefit. They are also more popular for projects like this so it might be that you might find more info about doing this with Arduino than with Wiimote, but I have not checked so I don't know. Just thought I would mention another option.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Thanks. I have found a few resources to use the Wiimote in PC video games and for doing music. Hopefully I can transpose this to Blender.
I'll write more here if I get some results.

Comment: Well eventually I found an addon that does exactly what I wanted, Virtucamera. The movement that you do with your Iphone/Ipad are synced with the Blender camera. Not Wiimote tho'.

Comment: Then, while searching, I found some clips of people that use the Wiimote to animate, they associate the buttons of the Wiimote to controllers, bones or drivers. It looks quite cool.